# Unit vector in $ds$ substitution (while changing coordinate systems)

Tags: integration, coordinate-systems

I had to calculate the line integral of a homogenous vector field $E=E.e_y$ from an angle $\phi=o$ to $\phi=\phi_{e}$ having a radius $\rho$. the formula normally is $\varphi=\int E \space ds$ but since the coordinate system used is cylindrical I converted $ds$ to $R\ dR\ d\phi$. However, the answer I got was wrong and in the provided solution. $ds$ was substituted by $Rd\varpThe session negotiation failed.

Error: Failed to authenticate user '' with PAMhi_e\varphi$ below I have added a picture of the problem.

[image: picture]

Comment: This is a line integral along the given circle. So $dS$ is really $\rho d\phi$ (arc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the notation $d\mathbf{s}$ is not a surface element, so it's not $Rdrd\phi$. It is a length, tangent to the curve. You need to decompose it into $ds_x$ and $ds_y$. The one that you care about is $ds_y$, since $ds_x\mathbf{e}_x\cdot\mathbf{E}=0$.

You can write $ds_y$ in terms of the angle:
$$ds_y=\rho\cos\phi d\phi$$
See if this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your curve is parametrized as

$$\mathbf{s}(\phi) = \rho(\cos\phi,\sin\phi,0),$$

hence

$$\mathrm{d}\mathbf{s} = \rho(-\sin\phi,\cos\phi,0)\,\mathrm{d}\phi.$$

Combined with $\mathbf{E} = (0,E,0)$, we get

$$\int\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{s} = \int_0^{\phi_e}E\rho\cos\phi\,\mathrm{d}\phi = E\rho \sin\phi_e.$$